# Ember.js: Data is being cleared from my fixtures array depending on how it is accessed

Tags: javascript, arrays, binding, ember.js, fixtures

I have 2 controllers. The first, KeywordsIndexController looks like this:

```
App.KeywordsIndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

    contentBinding: "App.Keyword.FIXTURES"

});
```

...the other, KeywordsNewController is a blank arraycontroller:

```
App.KeywordsNewController = Em.Controller.extend({
});
```

I also have 2 views, KeywordsIndexView and KeywordsNewView that each have a function in them. KeywordsIndexController is in charge of listing the keywords and deleting a single keyword. KeywordsNewController is responsible for adding a new keyword then routing back to the list of keywords (index). They look like this:

```
App.KeywordsIndexView = Em.View.extend({

    templateName: 'templates/keywords/index',

    delKeyword: function(e){
        var obj = App.Keyword.FIXTURES.findProperty("name", e._data.attributes.name);
            App.Keyword.FIXTURES.removeObject(obj);
        }

});

----------------------------------------

App.KeywordsNewView = Em.View.extend({

    templateName: 'templates/keywords/new',

    addKeyword: function(){
        App.Keyword.FIXTURES.pushObject({

            id: App.Keyword.length,
            name: newKey.value,
            scode: '55678',
            campaign: null

        });
        this.get('controller.target.router').transitionTo('keywords.index');
    }

});
```

**THE ISSUE**

Both of these events work on their own as expected. If you go straight to the new keyword page it works beautifully. The issue arises when you visit the keywords list page before trying to add a new keyword. When you go through that route you get these errors when it tries to add the new keyword:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Additionally, when i try to print out the App.Keyword.FIXTURES array it comes back as an empty class.

I am not sure what would cause this behavior and any thoughts/help is much appreciated.

**EXTRA CREDIT**

In a testing environment (i.e. FIXTURES) is there a better way to reference that object other than "App.Keyword.FIXTURES"?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with example of your code?

Answer (score 1):

> In a testing environment (i.e. FIXTURES) is there a better way to reference that object other than "App.Keyword.FIXTURES"?

Use `App.Keyword.all()` in `model` method of your route:

```
model: function(controller){
    return App.Keyword.all();
}
```

This is a *live* array which will be updated if some models will be added later.

Also, don't push objects into `FIXTURES`, just use `createRecord` to create a new object:

```
App.Keyword.createRecord({
    id: App.Keyword.length,
    name: newKey.value,
    scode: '55678',
    campaign: null
});
```